# SSRS chart: Dates in horizontal axis, Year as tick marks

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SQL Server Report (SSRS) with a chart in it.
The chart has Date as Horizonral axis. These are days from e.g. 01-01-2010 till now (01-01-2010, 02-01-2010, 03-01-2010, ..., 05-12-2014. It is quite a big (long) chart).
I would like to display (major) tick marks indicating start of each year only. So tick marks on 01-01-2011, 01-01-2012, 01-01-2013. No labels are necessary.
Is it possible to specify tick marks in such a way?

I am using Report Builder 3.0.
Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: I dont know about the tickmarks on axis but you can set the background color of start of the year date using conditional expression which will check if it is '01-01-yyyy'

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please specify, background of which element do you mean? Is is of a chart or some element of the chart?